# Working with a giant matrix with Java

Tags: java

I hava read a related question here [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493155/the-right-way-to-manage-a-big-matrix-in-java)

It was suggested there to work with a giant file and then use RandomAccessFile.

My problem is that a matrix(consists of "0" and "1", not sparse) could be really huge. For example, a row size could be 10^10000. I need an efficient way to store such a matrix. Also, I need to work with such file (if I would store my matrix in it) in that way:

Say, I have a giant file which contains sequences of numbers. Numbers in a sequence are divided by ","(first number shows the raw number, remaining numbers show places in matrix where "1"s stay). Sequences are divided by symbol "|". In addition, there is a symbol "||" which divide all of sequences into two groups. (that is a view of two matrixes. May be it is not efficient, but I don't know the way to make it better. Do you have any ideas? =) ) I have to read, for example, 100 numbers from an each row from a first group (extract a submatrix) and determine by them which rows I need to read from the second group.
So I need the function seek(). Would it work with such a giant file?

I am a newbie. May be there are some efficient ways to store and read such a data?

Comment: 10^10000????????? kinda joke?

Comment: 10 ^ 10,000 is a huge number, I do not think there are enough particles in universe represent it. did you make a mistake?

Comment: Since God coded the universe in lisp (http://xkcd.com/224/) I strongly suggest you look for solutions in that language

Comment: I think that's a googol raised to the hundredth power.  RAM is cheap nowadays, but not that cheap...

Answer (score 5):

There are about 10^80 atoms in the observable universe. So say you could store one bit in each atom, you need about 10^9920 universes about the same size as ours. Thats just to store one row.

How many rows were you condiering?  You will need 10^9920 universes per row.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you mean 10 000 entries and not 10^10000 Then you could use the BitSet class to store all in RAM (or you could use sth. like [hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop))

Comment: That problem is taken from cryptography. Matrixes could be absolutely random! Any size. Are there any efficient way to do the operations I methioned?

Ok, may be I got heated about the size of a matrix, but it really can be random... What should I do?

Comment: for large data take a look into hadoop or a database (or similar technologies to hadopp; bigtable?). I don't know if the performance is sufficient if you implement your own solution based on the file seek() method.

Comment: But would it be easy to use database to enter such a matrix? Also, do you know, what is the maximum size of a file Java will work with? I mean using RandomAccessFile

Comment: of course you will need to split the matrix into sub arrays (=>3d) if you are using a database. You should also specify what you want to do with that data: storing, searching, comparing, matching?